# How to break the loop if we are using dispatch_apply?

Tags: ios, iteration

if we are using GCD approach for iteration , how to break/stop the loop once the condition matched?

```
queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
dispatch_apply(count, queue, ^(size_t i) {
   printf("%u\n", i);
   //doing thread safe(also heavy) operation here
   if (condition) {
       //exit the loop
   }
});
```

Comment: `dispatch_apply` does not support any ability to stop early. It won't return until all `count` invocations are complete. Update your question with what you are trying to do so alternative solutions can be offered.

Comment: Thank you @rmaddy for the comment. I want to perform a thread safe operation inside a loop and once my condition satisfied I want to exit the loop. I have updated my question.

Comment: Why do you think `dispatch_apply` will make your operation thread safe?  The fact that you want to terminate early implies that any form of parallel execution is probably not suitable anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to cancel `dispatch_apply` as not all operations are completed sequentially but concurrently. The purpose of `dispatch_apply` is to parallelize a for-loop where all iterations are independent from other iterations. 
However you can use a boolean which indicates that the condition was satisfied. All pending operations are cancelled immediately as they are invoked.

```
__block BOOL stop = NO;
queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
dispatch_apply(count, queue, ^(size_t i) {
    if (stop)
        return;
    //Do stuff
    if (condition)
        stop = YES;
});
```

Comment: great. that wraps it for the analog of "break;" in for loops. What about "continue" ? how can I "jump" to the end of the current block - without canceling the other iterations?

Comment: You can just `return;`

Comment: Indeed. works like a charm, even if it looks kind-of strange in the context of Obj-C code.